# How can we dynamically allocate and grow an array

Tags: java, arrays, word-count

I am working on a project, but I cannot use any existing java data structures (ie, ArraysList, trees, etc)

I can only use arrays. Therefore, I need to dynamically update an array with new memory.

I am reading from a text file, and I pre-allocate 100 for the arrays memory:

```
   String [] wordList;
   int wordCount = 0;
   int occurrence = 1;
   int arraySize = 100;
   wordList = new String[arraySize];
   while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
         // Store the content into an array
         Scanner s = new Scanner(strLine);
         while(s.hasNext()) {
           wordList[wordCount] = s.next();
           wordCount++;
         } 
   }
```

Now this works fine for under 100 list items. br.readline is the buffered reader going through each line of a textfile. I have it then store each word into list and then increment my index (wordCount).

However, once I have a text file with more than 100 items, I get an allocation error.

How can I dynamically update this array (and thereby sort of reinvent the wheel)?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the fastest solution would be to count the lines in the input file (`wc -l filename` in 'nix) and allocate the array to the right size first time. All this copying is much slower than rewinding the file and reading it twice...

Comment: possible duplicate of [java dynamic array sizes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647260/java-dynamic-array-sizes)

Comment: Also, see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8438879/422353

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
String [] wordList;
int wordCount = 0;
int occurrence = 1;
int arraySize = 100;
int arrayGrowth = 50;
wordList = new String[arraySize];
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
     // Store the content into an array
     Scanner s = new Scanner(strLine);
     while(s.hasNext()) {
         if (wordList.length == wordCount) {
              // expand list
              wordList = Arrays.copyOf(wordList, wordList.length + arrayGrowth);
         }
         wordList[wordCount] = s.next();
         wordCount++;
     } 
}
```

Using `java.util.Arrays.copyOf(String[])` is basically doing the same thing as:

```
if (wordList.length == wordCount) {
    String[] temp = new String[wordList.length + arrayGrowth];
    System.arraycopy(wordList, 0, temp, 0, wordList.length);
    wordList = temp;
}
```

except it is one line of code instead of three. :)

Answer (score 5):

You allocate a new Array (double the capacity, for instance), and move all elements to it.

Basically you need to check if the `wordCount` is about to hit the `wordList.size()`, when it does, create a new array with twice the length of the previous one, and copy all elements to it (create an auxiliary method to do this), and assign `wordList` to your new array.

To copy the contents over, you *could* use `System.arraycopy`, but I'm not sure that's allowed with your restrictions, so you can simply copy the elements one by one:

```
public String[] createNewArray(String[] oldArray){
    String[] newArray = new String[oldArray.length * 2];
    for(int i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++) {
        newArray[i] = oldArray[i];
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

Proceed.

Comment: Or you could just use `array = Arrays.copyOf(array, newLength)`.

Comment: Yes, I know that. Like I said, that suggestion is stated in case he cannot use the builtin methods... the same way he cannot use an ArrayList, etc.

Answer (score 3):

you can not increase array size dynamically better you copy into new `array`. Use `System.arrayCopy` for that, it better than copying each element into new array. For reference
[Why is System.arraycopy native in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772152/why-is-system-arraycopy-native-in-java).

```
private static Object resizeArray (Object oldArray, int newSize) {
   int oldSize = java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(oldArray);
   Class elementType = oldArray.getClass().getComponentType();
   Object newArray = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(
         elementType, newSize);
   int preserveLength = Math.min(oldSize, newSize);
   if (preserveLength > 0)
      System.arraycopy(oldArray, 0, newArray, 0, preserveLength);
   return newArray;
}
```

Comment: Or you could just use `array = Arrays.copyOf(array, newLength)`.

Comment: Sure ... if you consider a bad re-implementation of a standard library method "the same".

Comment: @BrianRoach I hope you checked the library implementation, what do you mean *bad implementation*? could you please be specific.

Comment: Exactly that. You re-invented the wheel (unnecessary) *and* made it so explicit casts are required.

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't have value showing the OP *how* it works, just that the right answer is to use the standard library (and maybe change your example to use generics)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at implementation of [Java ArrayList](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList). Java `ArrayList` internally uses a fixed size array and reallocates the array once number of elements exceed current size. You can also implement on similar lines.

Comment: Or just use `array = Arrays.copyOf(array, newLength)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually create a new bigger array and copy over the items.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438879/expanding-an-array) may help

Answer (score 0):

Visual Basic has a nice function : `ReDim Preserve`.

Someone has kindly written an equivalent function - you can find it [here](http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Articles/Java%20Equivalent%20to%20VB%20ReDim%20Preserve.html). I think it does exactly what you are asking for (and you're not re-inventing the wheel - you're copying someone else's)...

Answer (score 0):

Lets take a case when you have an array of 1 element, and you want to extend the size to accommodate 1 million elements dynamically.

Case 1:

```
String [] wordList = new String[1];
String [] tmp = new String[wordList.length + 1];
for(int i = 0; i < wordList.length ; i++){
    tmp[i] = wordList[i];
}
wordList = tmp;
```

Case 2 (increasing size by a addition factor):

```
String [] wordList = new String[1];
String [] tmp = new String[wordList.length + 10];
for(int i = 0; i < wordList.length ; i++){
    tmp[i] = wordList[i];
}
wordList = tmp;
```

Case 3 (increasing size by a multiplication factor):

```
String [] wordList = new String[1];
String [] tmp = new String[wordList.length * 2];
for(int i = 0; i < wordList.length ; i++){
    tmp[i] = wordList[i];
}
wordList = tmp;
```

When extending the size of an Array dynamically, using Array.copy or iterating over the array and copying the elements to a new array using the for loop, actually iterates over each element of the array. This is a costly operation. Array.copy would be clean and optimized, still costly. So, I'd suggest increasing the array length by a multiplication factor.

How it helps is,

In case 1, to accommodate 1 million elements you have to increase the size of array 1 million - 1 times i.e. 999,999 times.

In case 2, you have to increase the size of array  1 million / 10 - 1 times i.e. 99,999 times.

In case 3, you have to increase the size of array by log<sub>2</sub>1 million - 1 time i.e. 18.9 (hypothetically).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Arr {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int a[] = {1,2,3};
        //let a[] is your original array
        System.out.println(a[0] + " " + a[1] + " " + a[2]);
        int b[];
        //let b[] is your temporary array with size greater than a[]
        //I have took 5
        b = new int[5];
        //now assign all a[] values to b[]
        for(int i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i ++)
            b[i] = a[i];
        //add next index values to b
        b[3] = 4;
        b[4] = 5;
        //now assign b[] to a[]
        a = b;
        //now you can heck that size of an original array increased
        System.out.println(a[0] + " " + a[1] + " " + a[2] + " " + a[3] + " " 
    + a[4]);
    }

}
```

Output for the above code is:

1 2 3

1 2 3 4 5