# How to declare string array[] of unknown size (JAVA)

Tags: java, arrays, string

I want my `String[] array;` to be static but I still don't know it's size.

Is there any way to declare string array of unknown size?
As much as possible I don't want to use ArrayList

Comment: ArrayList is just the thing you need for this purpose. I do not see any reason to avoid ArrayList.

Comment: Why not List?  Far better than array of the size changes.

Comment: Check out dynamic array http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647260/java-dynamic-array-sizes

Comment: Arrays have a fixed size which must be known when the array is created. If you need something to hold a variable number of elements, use a collection class such as `ArrayList` instead. See tutorial: [Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

Comment: The simplest option is to use an ArrayList.  Alternatively you can use an empty String[] to start with and copy it into a new String[] each time the size changes.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You don't need to know the array size when you *declare* it

```
String[] myArray;
```

but you do need to know the size when you *initialize* it (because **Java Virtual Machine needs to reserve a continuous chunk of memory for an array** upfront):

```
myArray = new String[256];
```

If you don't know what the size will need to be in the moment you initialize it, you need a `List<String>`, or you'll be forced to make your own implementation of it (which is almost certainly worse option).

Answer (score 3):

No, it needs to be declared, and thus have a length before you can set elements in it.

If you want to resize an array, you'll have to do something like: [Expanding an Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438879/expanding-an-array)

Answer (score 3):

```
String [] array = new String[1];
```

it will be garbage collected later after you init with a real array n elements.

```
array = new String[n];
```

ofcourse it has a performance decrease but it should be non-importance unless you repeat same for many different arrays.

Comment: `String[] busnum =  new String[1];`
`busnum[] = new String[(int)dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()];`  error, not a statement

Comment: String [] array; is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The [list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is better for manipulation of an "array" for which you don't know length.

Answer (score 1):

Using Java.util.ArrayList or LinkedList is the usual way of doing this. **With arrays that's not possible** as I know.

Example:

List unindexedVectors = new ArrayList();

unindexedVectors.add(2.22f);

unindexedVectors.get(2);

Answer (score -1):

My apologies to the nay-say-ers, this can be done easily.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Roll_2 {
static Random random = new Random();

public static void main(String[] args) {
int[] variableArray1 = init(random.nextInt(9)); // random size
int[] variableArray2 = init(random.nextInt(9)); // random size
int[] variableArray3 = init(random.nextInt(9)); // random size

randomaize(variableArray1); // randomize elements
randomaize(variableArray2); // randomize elements
randomaize(variableArray3); // randomize elements

print(variableArray1);  // print final
print(variableArray2);  // print final
print(variableArray3);  // print final
}
private static int[] init(int x) {
int[] arr = new int[x];
return arr;
}
private static void print(int[] body) {
System.out.print("[");
for (int i=0;i<body.length;i++) {
System.out.print(body[i]);
if (i<body.length-1) System.out.print(" ");
}
System.out.println("]");
}
private static void randomaize(int[] body) {
for (int i=0;i<body.length;i++) {
body[i] = random.nextInt(9);
}
}
}
```

> Sample Run 1:
>       [1 7 2]
>       [5 2 8 6 8 3 0 8]
>       []
>
> Sample Run 2: [2 5 6 8 0 7 0 6] [0 0 1] [2 1 2 1 6]
>
> Sample Run 3: [8 3 3] [7] [1 3 7 3 1 2]

Comment: That were different runs, thus different arrays were created. Try to access element with index greater than array size, and you will get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.